# Tomcat, change name of deploy dir for war file

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, war

This may not be a difficult question, but I probably do not have the right terminology and am not finding the answer.

When I deploy a war file in Tomcat (7), say, myapp-1.0.war, a new directory, myapp-1.0, is created under webapps. Is there a way to change the name of the new directory? e.g. When I deploy myapp-1.0.war, the new directory is named myapp? Is this configurable inside the war file somehow?

Comment: No.  Why would you want to?  If you want a different name, give your WAR a different name.

Comment: Is there any reason why the war file is not renamed to myapp?

Comment: you no need to track folder on server once your application deployed, if yes then why you want to configure?

Comment: you can include a 'context.xml' in the WEB-INF folder which Tomcat will use. Here you can specify unpackWAR="false", or use a different docBase (defaults to 'webapps' folder)

Comment: gradle auto concatenates the version to the war file. I'm sure this can be changed or worked around, but having the version in the war file name is somewhat of a convenience.

Comment: How about this: instead of naming the file myapp-1.0.war, name it myapp##1.war. The context path should then be /myapp. Seems tomcat has a naming convention for versions (however it may be container specific). http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this by adding a symlink to the webapps directory and placing my war file in a directory outside of the appBase. This way I was able to standardize the docBase in the server.xml. Now all I have to do is update the symlink when new versions are posted (and maybe restart the server). My configuration is posted at another question:

[Tomcat 7 symbolic link to war file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848047/tomcat-7-symbolic-link-to-war-file)