# Tomcat 7 symbolic link to war file

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7, war, symlink

I would like to have a symbolic link in tomcat's webapps directory that points to a war file at another place in my file system, and I would like that war file to be served as the default webapp. I have pieced together the following solution, but the app is not accessible from the browser.

I have a folder in my home directory ~/tomcat/webapps. The owner is tomcat7. In this folder, I have my war file, myapp-1.0.war.

In my /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps directory, I have a symbolic link:

```
myapp -> /home/[me]/tomcat/webapps/myapp-1.0.war.
```

In my /etc/tomcat7/server.xml, I have:

```
<Context docBase="/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/myapp" path="" reloadable="true" allowLinking="true"/>
```

Tomcat starts with no complaints in the logs, but my app is not accessible.
[host]:8080/rest/ returns 404, where it would normally take me to the home page.

I partially want to do this to abstract out the version number from my war file. Any ideas why this is not working, or what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Fixed it. I must have stared at it too long. Basically, the symlink needs to have a .war extension.

Comment: these are both in the ```/webapps``` directory?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. I have a symlink in the tomcat7/webapps directory. The actual war being linked to is in an external directory of my creation that happens to be named tomcat/webapps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. The symlink in the webapps directory needs to have a .war extension. So, instead of:

```
myapp -> /home/[me]/tomcat/webapps/myapp-1.0.war
```

It should be:

```
myapp.war -> /home/[me]/tomcat/webapps/myapp-1.0.war
```

I was also able to shorten the value of the docBase attribute as below:

```
<Context docBase="myapp" path="" reloadable="true" allowLinking="true"/>
```